# How to create an imbalanced dataset without leading to classifier overfitting

Tags: unbalanced-classes, multilabel

I am working on semi-supervised multi-label classification method that intrinscly deal with the imbalance problem, commonly present in multi-label datasets. That's why, i want to create an imbalanced dataset on which i will test the performance of my approach.  I just want to know approximately the  number of training examples that are sufficient for training majority labels, and the minimum number of examples for minority ones I also ask if the dataset should contains few minority labels (with insufficient examples for learning the labels)  to avoid the bad performance of classifier

I create a dataset that contains 8 majority labels, and 5 minority labels 
(13 labels in total) assigned to 2700 examples .Does the dataset sufficient for evaluating a multi-label classification approach?

In my dataset, minority labels are represented by 120 exemples in minimum, i.e 40 examples in the labeled dataset, while the majority labels have at least 300 exemples in the whole dataset,  i.e. 100 labeled training exemples).

I would be happy if someone help me in how to decide these parameters that extremly influence the classifier behavior.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify on "...while taking into consideration the imbalance problem."? This sounds like your method itself is supposed to handle issues related to imbalanced data, but you're also asking how to avoid creating a dataset that has problems due to imbalanced data.

Comment: I mean i will propose a semi-supervised multi-label classification approach that intrinscly deal with the imbalance problem, commonly present in multi-label datasets. That's why, i want to create an imbalanced dataset on which i will test the performance of my approach.  I just want to know approximately the  number of training examples that are sufficient for training majority labels, and the minimum number of examples for minority ones. I also ask if the dataset contains many minority labels (with insufficient examples for learning the labels) influence badly the classifier performance.